# Printf in awk with the same space between columns

Tags: awk

I have a data file with five columns, when I use the printf command in awk, the output isn't aligned.

```
118  96  105  106  0
119  97  106  107  0
120  98  107  108  0
121  99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111  23  0
125  11  12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
```

I need to use all columns with the same space separator, independent is the number are tens, hundreds, or thousands like this:

```
118   96  105  106  0
119   97  106  107  0
120   98  107  108  0
121   99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111   23  0
125   11   12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
```

How can I do this using printf in awk?

I'm using this:

```
awk '{printf "%d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d\n", $1,"",$2,"",$3,"",$4,"",$5}' test
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: If you want the data in the columns to align, you do *not* want the "same space between columns".  Quite the opposite.

Comment: The simplest way to get (almost) aligned output is to use a tab as the separator.

Comment: `printf "%d %s %d %s %d %s %d %s %d\n", $1,"",$2,"",$3,"",$4,"",$5` = `printf "%d  %d  %d  %d  %d\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5` since printing null strings does exactly that - print nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `column` on the output rather than trying to format it with awk:

```
$ column -t -R'1,2,3,4,5' file
118   96  105  106  0
119   97  106  107  0
120   98  107  108  0
121   99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111   23  0
125   11   12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
```

Your version of `column` may already support `-R0` which means "right align all columns" so you don't need to list them, see https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1306.

As [@glennjackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) pointed out in comments:

> The BSD-derived `column` on MacOS does not have the `-R` option. Have to do `rev file | column -t | rev` on a mac

Comment: The BSD-derived `column` on MacOS does not have the -R option. Have to do `rev file | column -t | rev` on a mac

Comment: @glennjackman I added a note about that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most `printf` formats allow the width to be supplied as an argument to a `*` format specifier, eg:

```
printf "%*s", 5 "abc"
```

Is evaulated as:

```
printf "%5s, "abc"
```

One `awk` idea making use of this `printf/*` feature:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
              w[i]= length($i) > w[i] ? length($i) : w[i]    # find max width for each column
          next
        }
        { pfx=""
          for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
              printf "%s%*s", pfx, w[i], $i
              pfx="  "                                       # (aligned) column delimiter == 2 spaces for columns 2 to NF
          }
          print ""                                           # terminate current line
        }
' five.dat five.dat
```

**NOTES:**

- requires 2 passes of the input file (could be rewritten to use a single pass but will need to store the entire file in memory)
- assumes the minimum delimiter between (aligned) columns is 2 spaces

This generates:

```
118   96  105  106  0
119   97  106  107  0
120   98  107  108  0
121   99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111   23  0
125   11   12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that requires two passes of the data (hence the `file file` in the end):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {                                   # first pass
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(m[i]=="" || m[i]<length($i))            # get max field widths
            m[i]=length($i)
    next
}
{                                                  # second pass
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%" m[i] "s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:"  ")  # output two spaces in between
}' file file                                       # two passes, twice the file
```

Output:

```
118   96  105  106  0
119   97  106  107  0
120   98  107  108  0
121   99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111   23  0
125   11   12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 easiest solution are: 1) pipe the output to `column -t`, 2) use a tab separator (doesn't completely align the text, but for the sample input is sufficient, and 3) print each column on a fixed width.

```
$ cat input
118  96  105  106  0
119  97  106  107  0
120  98  107  108  0
121  99  108  109  0
122  100  109  110  0
123  101  110  111  0
124  102  111  23  0
125  11  12  112  0
126  103  112  113  0
127  104  113  114  0
128  105  114  115  0
$ awk '($1=$1) || 1' OFS=\\t input
118     96      105     106     0
119     97      106     107     0
120     98      107     108     0
121     99      108     109     0
122     100     109     110     0
123     101     110     111     0
124     102     111     23      0
125     11      12      112     0
126     103     112     113     0
127     104     113     114     0
128     105     114     115     0
$ awk '{printf "%5s%5s%5s%5s%5s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' input
  118   96  105  106    0
  119   97  106  107    0
  120   98  107  108    0
  121   99  108  109    0
  122  100  109  110    0
  123  101  110  111    0
  124  102  111   23    0
  125   11   12  112    0
  126  103  112  113    0
  127  104  113  114    0
  128  105  114  115    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` to do that:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (w[i]<length($i)) w[i]=length($i); next}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%*s%s", w[i], $i, i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}
' file file
```

Prints:

```
118  96 105 106 0
119  97 106 107 0
120  98 107 108 0
121  99 108 109 0
122 100 109 110 0
123 101 110 111 0
124 102 111  23 0
125  11  12 112 0
126 103 112 113 0
127 104 113 114 0
128 105 114 115 0
```

Then if you want to field size to increase, just add that:

```
awk -v wp=5 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (w[i]<length($i)+wp) w[i]=length($i)+wp; next}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%*s%s", w[i], $i, i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}
' file file
 118       96      105      106      0
 119       97      106      107      0
 120       98      107      108      0
 121       99      108      109      0
 122      100      109      110      0
 123      101      110      111      0
 124      102      111       23      0
 125       11       12      112      0
 126      103      112      113      0
 127      104      113      114      0
 128      105      114      115      0
```